# How to find time zone set in Panasonic EXIF

Tags: camera, photo, exif, exiftool

The Panasonic Lumix GX8 doesn't have a GPS, so generally doesn't know where it is. However the time can be set manually and a time zone set. But I can't figure out if that information is available in the EXIF data.

TimeStamp shows UTM time and all the other time related EXIF data is in local time (whatever time is set for the camera. So the camera is storing the offset, but I wanted get it directly.

In Ruby

```
require …
photo = MiniExiftool.new(fn) # fn is a filename
timeZone =  (photo.CreateDate - photo.TimeStamp)/3600
puts "timeZone: #{timeZone}"
```

works as expected. But can the offset be found directly via EXIF?

exiftool.org has

```
 Panasonic TimeInfo Tags

Index1  Tag Name    Writable    Values / Notes
0   PanasonicDateTime   undef[8]
```

but PanasonicDateTime is null for the GX8.

```
exiftool -G1 -a -s -time:all "file.rw2"
[System]        FileModifyDate                  : 2021:12:05 18:40:45-08:00
[System]        FileAccessDate                  : 2021:12:05 19:17:28-08:00
[System]        FileInodeChangeDate             : 2021:12:05 18:40:45-08:00
[IFD0]          ModifyDate                      : 2021:11:25 15:31:34
[ExifIFD]       DateTimeOriginal                : 2021:11:25 15:31:34
[ExifIFD]       CreateDate                      : 2021:11:25 15:31:34
[Panasonic]     TimeStamp                       : 2021:11:25 22:31:34
[ExifIFD]       SubSecTime                      : 277
[ExifIFD]       SubSecTimeOriginal              : 277
[ExifIFD]       SubSecTimeDigitized             : 277
[GPS]           GPSTimeStamp                    : 22:31:34
[GPS]           GPSDateStamp                    : 2021:11:25
[ExifIFD]       DateTimeOriginal                : 2021:11:25 15:31:34
[ExifIFD]       CreateDate                      : 2021:11:25 15:31:34
[ExifIFD]       SubSecTimeOriginal              : 277
[ExifIFD]       SubSecTimeDigitized             : 277
[GPS]           GPSTimeStamp                    : 22:31:34
[GPS]           GPSDateStamp                    : 2021:11:25
[Composite]     SubSecCreateDate                : 2021:11:25 15:31:34.277
[Composite]     SubSecDateTimeOriginal          : 2021:11:25 15:31:34.277
[Composite]     SubSecModifyDate                : 2021:11:25 15:31:34.277
[Composite]     GPSDateTime                     : 2021:11:25 22:31:34Z
[Composite]     GPSDateTime                     : 2021:11:25 22:31:34Z
```

Comment: Have you check the output using exiftool?  Try this command `exiftool -G1 -a -s -time:all file.jpg`  That will show all time related tags and their locations.

Comment: It's unlikely that ruby will be able to find the Panasonic specific tags that you mention finding with exiftool as those are MakerNotes, which are proprietary tags held in a subsection of the EXIF block.  There's no consistancy in the way various camera manufacturers write MakerNotes, and can even vary between different cameras from the same manufacturer.  And that doesn't take into account that sometimes the MakerNotes are encrypted.

Comment: @StarGeek. I've been using exiftool on the command line and your options help limit what needs to be read. I'll add it to the OP. Thanks for the info on MakerNotes. As I mentioned exiftool.org had some Panasonic fields. and many do show up, but guess not the one I want. I'll just use my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

EXIF supports UTC offsets:

- `9010.H` "OffsetTime" (to augment `132.H` "DateTime")
- `9011.H` "OffsetTimeOriginal" (to augment `9003.H` "DateTimeOriginal")
- `9011.H` "OffsetTimeDigitized" (to augment `9004.H` "DateTimeDigitized")

Source: [CIPA's Exif standard 2.31 from 2016](https://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/download_e.html?DC-008-Translation-2016-E), semantically page 49, digitally page 54.

You already see other time augmentation fields: `SubSecTime`, `SubSecTimeOriginal` and `SubSecTimeDigitized` are also optional for providing milliseconds. Now it's up to the EXIF writer to turn your timezone into a UTC offset and write the additional fields. If any Panasonic software is not writing it into official EXIF fields then seek their support.

Linking [Why don't Exif tags contain time zone information?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/97149)

Comment: Thank you. My camera is Exif 2.30, just before this change. My camera came out mid 2016 and except for the very high end, don't get updated that often. Just checked, the last update was in 2016. I'll continue using my workaround.